# The name 'placeholderName' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net

I have added placeholder to a page as below.

```
<tr > 
 <td >
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phMemberName" runat="server" >
  </asp:PlaceHolder>
 </td>
 <td>
 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phMemberTextboxes" runat="server">
 </asp:PlaceHolder> 
</td>
 </tr>
```

I am adding controls(checkboxes) to it dynamically to it.
It works fine but it throws an error if run in debug mode.
What is the reason ?

The error is

> The name 'phMemberName' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Does this PlaceHolder contains in any parent control?

Comment: go through this link: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3826/adding-controls-to-placeholders-dynamically/

Comment: Dor: I have edited the question. 
Fraz: PlaceHolder is not contained in any Parent Control

Comment: can you post the code where you use the PlaceHolder, and where the error is thrown?

Comment: Post the code you're using to dynamically add the controls to the placeholders. The error message suggests that you're referencing `placeholderName` somewhere in your code, and it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be  solved the issue using FindControl()
like ,

```
PlaceHolder phMName = (PlaceHolder)form1.FindControl("ControlID");
```

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024623/why-to-use-findcontrol)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you've made a typo?
"The name 'placeholderName' does not exist in the current context"
Should that not be "phMemberName"

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the aspx.designer.cs file. Since this file essentially glues the aspx markup controls to the CodeBehind page(aspx.cs), absence of this file can cause the CodeBehind page to not understand where the "placeholderName" placeholder control exists and hence the error "does not exist in current context".