# Why to use FindControl...?

Tags: asp.net

I was facing an issue where i was adding textboxes dynamically to a placedHolder.

**placeHolder Declaration:**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phTextBoxes" runat="server" >
  </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

**Assignment of TextBoxes**

```
 ...if (phTextBoxes!= null) phTextBoxes.Controls.Add(txt);
```

But when i build the application i got the error

**The name 'phTextBoxes' does not exist in the current context**
I have solved the issue by using **FindControl()** like below.

```
PlaceHolder phtxt = (PlaceHolder)form1.FindControl("phTextBoxes");
```

and then added control to phtxt.
The error is gone.
But i would like to know why was the old placeHolder giving an error and how did the FindControl found it.

Comment: The auto-generated `phTextBoxes` member might have been deleted (or not generated) by the designer or it might be on another ASCX page (i.e. "not exist in the current context").

Comment: Is your PlaceHolder control inside another control? Or is it on a master page that you're trying to access through a child page?

Comment: No it not inside any control. and i am not using master page

Answer (score 0):

As @GrahamClark mentioned before, you could be missing something. There's no way not to see phTextBoxes in code behind unless it is inside another control, such as GridView, etc.. Make sure your place holder is not inside any other control.

Another thing, on the top of your Designer window (aspx or ascx file), make sure you have referenced the related class name in **CodeBehind**/**CodeFile**, and **Inherits** if necessary.

Example1: I have a usercontrol called **UC1**, in the ascx file I should declare the class name as follows:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Cart.ascx.cs"
 Inherits="UserControls_UC1" %>
```

Example2: I have a ASPX page called **Default**, in the aspx file I should declare the class name as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
 Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Comment: No that is the point, i forced my self to put the situation for discussion. It is not contained in any user Control or other server controls like GridView. hierarchy of control is ((Form--->HTMLTable---->TD-----> PlaceHolder))